# Custom modal window with image in header

Tags: ios, swift

i would ask if it is possible to change to base modal window to look like my image? (only layout test)

[image: Modal window layout test]

I can easiliy set up an image with:

```
    var barButtonImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "header_test.png")
    var barButtonImageView = UIImageView(image: barButtonImage)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = barButtonImageView
```

But i am not able to set it outside the view - is that possible? And if, how?

EDIT:

Thanks for the info about using clipsToBounds. I set it to titleview and bar to false, but the image is not outside the modal (but it is over the top of my UITableView in the modal window)

```
    self.navigationItem.titleView.clipsToBounds = false
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds  = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to embed your visual stuff inside another view, with that view's background set to transparent.

Or, you could play around with the "clips subviews" property of your view, to allow the round graphic to not get clipped at the edges of the superview that contains it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check for the clips subviews. The modal is animated so add the additional image from the other view will be not that easy i guess.